# Plots not displaying well in R

Tags: r

When I plot a graph in R it comes out quite small. Additionally, it sometimes plots four graphs with me asking it to do so. Does anyone have a fix for this?

plot(seg.hc)

when I would try to plot that or any other plot, it plot the graph on the same page as other plots, up to four plots.

It turns out that I had par() turned on from a previous exercise. A user alerted me to that resolution and it worked.

Luis

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... what have you tried? What is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have set `par` to something weird inadvertently. For the multiple graphs, set `par(mfrow=c(1, 1))` to make the window only show one graph at a time. Small graphs might have something to do with `par(mai)` instead. Check `?par` for more information.

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I used par() for an exercise. Did not realize that I had to reset it, I will do that from now on. Thank you.

Comment: @Luis if this answer solved your question remember to mark it as accepted. Also, please edit your question as I mentioned in a comment, so it shows the code that you had trouble with. This will help you in the future with other questions you have (other users will be more likely to help) and will also serve as reference for other users with the same problem as you